# MVC: Controller's action parameter as nullable Guid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, guid, nullable

In this function

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create_Summary(Guid? appointmentId)
    {
        if (appointmentId.HasValue)
        {
            var appointment = _appointmentRepository.GetAppointmentDetails(appointmentId);
            var summary = new CreateAppointmentSummary
            {
                NameOrSubject = appointment.Subject,
                Location = appointment.Location,
                DescriptionOrRemarks = appointment.Description
            };
            return View(summary);
        }
        else
        {
            var summary = new CreateAppointmentSummary();
            return View(summary);
        }

    }
```

I get error : `Cannot convert System.Guid? to System.Guid` while calling the repository function.

What I want to do make this action to be able to be called with some null guid value as well from some other view.
But if they call with some not null guid value then call the resposiotry function to do some search.

But i'm having trouble to make this work.

Comment: `appointmentId.Value`

Comment: in this line: var appointment = _appointmentRepository.GetAppointmentDetails(appointmentId.Value);

Comment: I looked away for 5 or 8 minutes and everyone and their cat replied...  Put it where they all said: on the `GetAppointmentDetails` call. See the answer by @Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Brandon said - you need this when you call the repository function.

```
var appointment = _appointmentRepository.GetAppointmentDetails(appointmentId.Value);
```

`Guid?` and `Guid` are totally different types; `GetAppointmentDetails` requires `Guid`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
(Guid?) new Guid(appointmentId)
```

just cast it: (Guid?)(new Guid(myString))

there is also an implicit cast, so this would work fine as well: Guid? g = new Guid(myString);